# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination] while depositing on etherdelta

Tags: blockchain, tokens, myetherwallet, etherscan, etherdelta

I have been trying to deposit a token on etherdelta from myetherwallet wallet but I keep getting this error

Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination]

Here are some screenshots

[image]
[image]

Please I really need help I have set gas price to 20, Then 5 and then 4 Still it fails. Please any help is appreciated, I have lost more than $10 trying to do this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a transacton id on a block explorer? Bad jump is a generic error can't help without more info.

Comment: After typing the address by hand (text would have been much easier!), I was able to find the two transactions: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa745d8059b31b7c99a90359da5210143144dba5910e0d146b04a6762aa8574a0 and https://etherscan.io/tx/0x87759eda823d3a821a617d92e94b07f2abc0672cea7bfb8bc389f1d4ffad6ad1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that EqualToken assesses a fee for each transfer, so although you approved EtherDelta to take a certain number of tokens, you can actually only transfer that number of tokens less the fee, which is, I believe, 1%.

Based on your current balance and the required 1% fee, you should be able to transfer 29411.1564788 tokens to EtherDelta. Try again with that amount.
 (In case it makes things easier, using the 18 decimal places, that amount is `0x63a61c9ee7bae800000` in hex.)